# Functional programming cases in memory allocation

Tags: c, memory-management, functional-programming

I've been reading about functional programming, and I was curious about some effects on the program in certain cases of running.

For my current situation I have a vector in C (array of doubles), and it is frequent that I use this vector in a computation that I want a "return vector," but I do not want to allocate extra memory, so I use a signature such as

```
void compute(vector* input, vector* output);
```

Where I use aliasing on the same input vector to save the output without having allocate extra memory for a new output vector.

Now for functional programming, my experience is limited to the Mathematica programming language and a little common lisp, but I am curious about the effect this would have. Say I have a vector v, and I program the same computation in a functional language. In Mathematica, I would have the statement:

```
v = compute(v)
```

In other standard functional languages, from my understanding of reading is that these objects are immutable, so v shouldn't change, and that v would be reassigned as a new vector, deallocating the old vector. I would like to know if my understanding is accurate or not, and if not what happens instead of my misunderstanding. I'm aware of lazy evaluation, and would also like to know how these systems would be different in cases of using and not using lazy evaluation.

Thank you.

Edit 1: Asked for a concrete situation about where I am coming from. The one project I am working on is a ray tracer where it is often the case that I need to request vector information for lighting or something to that effect, this data is stored via a pointer passed to a function, and the target storage vector is allocated outside the function. What my understanding is of functional programming, and as a comment had been posted is that when I do something similar, since the vectors would be immutable I cannot pass a pointer to this function for the vector to be modified, and instead the function would return a newly allocated vector:

v = compute(v)

And v would be a newly allocated vector. My original question was the accuracy of this claim, and as someone has posted in support of this claim, my next question that wouldn't this be considered a possible point of wasted memory?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. Making array-based algorithms work in FP often requires replacing data structures and/or rewriting code (in the compiler or by hand) in such a way that array updates need not allocate large temporaries.

Comment: Do you have a concrete situation in mind? That might be easier to discuss.

Comment: the answer may very be different for different functional programing languages they are not all the same

Comment: If your input array is immutable, there is no choice: the result will have to be allocated in fresh memory. Except maybe the compiler can proove that the old content of v is not accessible anymore from anywhere and so could reuse it.

Comment: You wouldn't do `v = compute(v)` at all because then `v` would be mutable. The compiler doesn't necessarily allocate a new array under the hood – it just needs to look like it did. This is called *stream fusion*. There is a lot to read about [performant arrays in functional programming](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrays) because there is no silver bullet, and they all make different tradeoffs.

Comment: Functional languages use a garbage collector for memory management.  Invented in 1959 by John McCarthy, he needed one for Lisp.  GC easily supports functions returning objects.

Comment: @kqr not necessarily true in the sense that the immutable data could store somewhere an "V" is a representation of that data. In other words it depends on what "v" is within the functionnal programming syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article give a good description of the data structure programming involved in immutable fonctionnal programming paradigm

http://www.infoq.com/articles/in-depth-look-clojure-collections

The problem with C is that you really need a lot of discipline to use immutable concepts. That being said, some scheme virtual machines are implemented in C. (Note that scheme is not immutable. But functionnal)